# php array foreach, древо массива

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Есть следующий массив:

```
   $arr = array(
      0 => array(
           0=>'three',
           1=>1,
           2=>''
       ),
      1 => array(
           0=>'two',
           1=>2,
           2=>''
       ),
      2 => array(
           0=>'one',
           1=>'',
           2=>''
       )
    );
```

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы массив $arr[0] был передан в $arr[1][2], и этот измененный массив, был передан в массив $arr[2][2];

Я пытаюсь это сделать так:

```
   $newarr = array();
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
             if(empty($v[1])) $newarr[] = $arr[$k]; 
             else $arr[$v[1]][2] = $v;
    }
    print_r($newarr);
```

Но получается следующее:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => one
            [1] => 
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => two
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 
                )

        )

)
```

Я знаю что можно использовать ссылки, рекурсию, но сейчас я просто хочу понять, что я сделал не так, ведь по идее в цикле форич, мы присваиваем нулевой массив, в одно из значений первого, а полный+нулевой, попадает в значение второго массива, но почему то в результате, я получил второй массив, в котором внутри расположен первый, но в первом нет нулевого.

Comment: @Эдуард цикл нужен так как в будущем код будет дополняться, это просто база.

Comment: ещё один момент - если вам в цикле foreach нужно изменять исходный массив, то значение в цикл нужно передавать по ссылке. Иначе вот эта запись `$arr[$v[1]][2] = $v;` не имеет никакого смысла.

Comment: @Эдуард я тоже думал про ссылку, но разве если во время форича, изменить исходный массив, то во время итерации цикл будет видеть этот массив в том состоянии которое было в начале цикла?

Comment: ну вы же обращаетесь по конкретным ключам: `$arr[$v[1]][2]` и разницы нет, в цикле или за его пределами. А вот если вы хотите изменить текущий массив, то из форича это можно сделать только по ссылке.

Comment: Как то не понятно что должно быть в конце. Дайте иерархию массива который вы хотите получить

Comment: @Эдуард я уже несколько часов не могу понять, то ли я с ума сошел, то ли что, в этом примере - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8f98a5bdd95c8fd9aac6656dd28e20d78de41897 я изменяю значение следующего массива в фориче, перед тем как начнется его итерация, то есть по возрастанию, и все работает. В примере же который скинул я, я добавляю в следующий элемент массива данные, а в после следующий, должен попасть следующий массив с новыми данными, а этого не происходит.

Comment: @RazGalstyan ему нужно результат такого присваивания, только в цикле:  
`$arr[2][2] = $arr[1][2] = $arr[0];` [результат](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d6e3624878401d8f6c93b1a6f3ccce4f4c9819b1)

Comment: @Alexey `$arr[$k]` -- это ссылка, `$v` --  не ссылка. Когда вы делаете `$arr[$v[1]][2] = $v` значение `$arr[$v[1]][2]` меняется, но `$v` на следующей итерации не изменяется. Заменив присваивание на `$arr[$v[1]][2] = $arr[$k];` вы получите, то что хотите.